# What can cause WPF binding to break (using ADO.net)?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, ado.net

I'm been on this problem for 3 days now, and I'm out of options. Don't know what else to do. I have a UserControl with TextBoxes inside, all defined similarly as such:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFreeFormat" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     KeyUp="txtFreeFormat_KeyUp" PreviewKeyDown="txtFreeFormat_PreviewKeyDown" TextChanged="txtFreeFormat_TextChanged"
                     Text="{Binding [FREEFORMATADDRESSUI], Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource FreeFormatOnlyConverter}, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsLocationEnabled, ElementName=LocationUserControl}"
                     IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly, ElementName=LocationUserControl}"/>
```

This TextBox exists within a WPF UserControl which exists within an ElementHost in a Win32 application.

I'm setting the WPF UserControl's DataContext to a DataView. I basically want the data to update anytime it gets updated in the DataView, not vice-versa, hence why I have a OneWay binding.

The user is allowed to type in it, but I don't perform any explicit Source updates when the user is typing.

My weird problem is that certain places in the application, this control works fine, the binding is perfect. Other places in the application, when the DataView updates its data, the WPF UserControls' UI doesn't update. I have traces everywhere possible and there are no binding errors. So the WPF UserControls' DataContext is up-to-date, but the UI is not reflecting those changes.

What else can I look for? What can cause a binding to be disconnected from a DataView?

Thanks!!!

### UPDATE:

I can't believe it still doesn't work after using the changes specified by Damascus. I even went as deep as calling my own function to reset the binding AFTER the DataView is updated:

```
Public Sub RefreshBinding()
    If WPFUserControl IsNot Nothing AndAlso WPFUserControl.DataContext IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dv As DataView = WPFUserControl.DataContext
        WPFUserControl.DataContext = Nothing
        WPFUserControl.DataContext = dv
    End If
End Sub
```

I noticed that at this point the converters don't fire anymore. When the DataContext = Nothing, the fields don't clear either.

You can now see why I've been on this for 3 days   :(

### UPDATE 2:

Noticed something new...we're getting somewhere. As soon as I type in the textbox, the binding seems to detach, I get this warning in my output window:

BindingExpression (hash=31836339): Detach

So I've reverted my TextBox back to a Two-Way binding with an Explicit mode for UpdateSourceTrigger. This has stopped that warning, but I'm still getting my weird behavior.

All explained here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3d092257-f5a9-4dc5-b9ee-ac1f0538df71/

Comment: Have you verified that the DataView raises its `PropertyChanged` event when the data is changed?

Comment: Have you tried adding `UpdateSourceTrigger` to your Text binding> It should be the following: `Text="{Binding [FREEFORMATADDRESSUI], Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource FreeFormatOnlyConverter}, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` . This will force the UI to be updated every time the property is updated (and would require your property to fire the `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: @Damascus: Nice one, that really could be the problem as especially for the `Text` property the default value is `LostFocus`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

Comment: I'll give it a try. But isn't that only appropriate for TwoWay bindings??

Comment: No, it's appropriate for every binding! As @DanielHilgarth said, the default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for a `Text` binding is `LostFocus` , so the binding will definitely not update itself every time the bound property is changed

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample project to reproduce that problem.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, I haven't found a solution. Instead I've decided to listen to the `ColumnChanged` event of the DataView's `DataTable` and call the corresponding `BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()` on the target `TextBox` control. And this worked for me!